# Remove boolean and add list in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to modify gender field, 
Initially i have declared gender field as boolean true or false. but now i want it to be changed as list (Male, Female, Other).

```
class AddExtraFieldsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :phone_number, :string
    add_column :users, :date_of_birth, :datetime
    add_column :users, :gender, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :users, :live_in, :string
    add_column :users, :description, :text

  end
end
```

Can i modify as following.... please let me know the correct way...

i thought of doing `rails g migration RemovegenderFromUsers gender:boolean`
then `rake db:migrate` followed by creating new one

```
rails g migration AddGenderToUsers gender:select
```

user.rb

```
GENDER_TYPES = ["Male", "Female", "Other"]
```

html

```
<%= f.select :gender,  User::GENDER_TYPES %>
```

Is above mentioned process correct or any other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select is not a database field type if you want to do it then do it like this

```
rails g migration AddGenderToUsers gender:integer
```

In migration file change it to like this:

```
change_column :users, :gender, :integer, default: 0
```

For form page do this:

```
<%= f.select :gender, User::GENDER_TYPES.each_with_index.map { |gender, index| [gender, index] } %>
```

And in user model you can define function to get gender name to display

```
def gender_name
  GENDER_TYPES[gender]
end
```

Comment: Or alternatively, you could define `gender` to be a `string`. This will cause slightly slower performance, although most likely the difference will be negligible.

Comment: If you are going to declare an array of different genders, consider using an enum since you will have a number of rails inbuilt methods to assist you in handling the gender values.

Comment: 1 ) shall i write change_column :users, :gender, :integer, default: 0 in already generated migration file or newly generated AddGenderToUsers file ?  2) Where can i declare Male Female Other.

Comment: 1) If you have already generated AddGenderToUsers then rollback that migration and add new migration which will change type from boolean to integer

Comment: 2) In user.rb specify GENDER_TYPES = ["Male", "Female", "Other"]

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Ahmad Hussain is correct . List is not a database field type . 
You should generate a migration to change the column type :

```
**change_column :table_name, :column_name,  :type**
```